# Virtual Host XAMPP on port 8080 doesn't works fine

Tags: php, apache, iis, xampp, virtualhost

I want to run a Vhost on XAMPP but redirecting to port :8080. The issue here is that i have IIS running on port :80 and Apache on port :8080 and those are my config files to try to run my proyect on a virtual host:

**hosts file**

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1   www.goviaje.com
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:8080
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
   ServerAdmin localhost:8080
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost:8080
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/goviaje/"
  ServerName www.goviaje.com:8080
  ServerAlias goviaje.com:8080
 <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/goviaje">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

***All the necesary modules in httpd.conf are enabled***

Ok, when i type "www.goviaje.com" in my browser, it send me to IIS main page (localhost:80) and i need go to **localhost:8080/goviaje/**

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Port 80 is the default HTTP port so all browsers will default to it.  If you need to specify the port, it needs to be part of the URL: `http://localhost:8080/goviage/`.  It is possible to port forward with a firewall, which would bypass IIS (making it inaccessible), or to make a redirect from the IIS installation.  Why do you need two web servers on a single machine?

Comment: You could try with different IPs instead of different ports. You can use whole 127.0.0.0/8 network, so you could configure Apache to listen e.g. on 127.0.0.2 (and of course an appropriate entry in hosts file is required)

Comment: I need two web servers because i have .NET projects and PHP projects. The think is that i have some resources from the data base with an absolute path ( www.goviaje.com/imgs/* ), so when i see the project, i can't view the images, for example.

I'm gonna try changing IP address.

Thks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `www.goviaje.com:8080` as a website URL in order to reach Apache, because default HTTP port is 80, therefore IIS is serving your requests. Also,of course, you can configure your IIS as a forwarding proxy.